# Swap columns from two sql server tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, swap

I would like to know if there is anyway I can compare two columns in SQL Server.

The two columns are located in two different tables.

When the column 1's value is smaller than the column 2's value:
I want to replace the value of the column 1 with the value of the column 2.

Comment: Can you please post the structure of your tables?

Comment: the two tables have the same structure, I have tree columns in each tables and the same amount of rows inserted.
The two columns I want to compare are INT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update table1 t1
set    t1.col1 = (select t2.col2
                  from   table2 t2
                  where  t2.id = t1.id
                  and    t1.col1 < t1.col2)
```

Something like that should do it easily.

The only tricky point I see is matching the row from table2 to the row from table1. In my example, I supposed both tables share an unique "id" column which enables easy matching. Modify the query with something more appropriate.

Comment: In SQL SERVER you cannot add nicknames to tables in UPDATE. So 'UPDATE table1 t1' will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
update tablename set column1=column2
from table1 inner join table2 on joincondition
where column1 < column2;
```

Hard to be more spesific without the actual table structure.